# Vim: Wrap a plugin mapping with my own expression

Tags: plugins, configuration, vim

I have a plugin which has the following mapping:

```
:i <CR>          <CR><Plug>DiscretionaryEnd
```

I'd like to also create my own expression for `<CR>` which falls through to this original mapping. However, when I do something like this:

```
:inoremap <expr> <CR> test ? '<CR><Plug>DiscretionaryEnd' : '<Esc>'
```

<kbd>CR</kbd> prints `\n<Plug>DiscretionaryEnd` rather than just `\n` followed by a delegation to the plugin's `DiscretionaryEnd` function.

`:h <Plug>` says it's used for internal mappings, so I'm probably going about this wrong. But I figure there's a way to wrap a plugin's behavior without diving into the internals of it. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's generally recommended to [use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html), because it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion, this is an exception to the rule.

In an expression mapping, the mapping applies to the expression itself, not the returned stream of characters.

```
:imap <expr> <CR> test ? '<CR><Plug>DiscretionaryEnd' : '<Esc>'
```